# Mathematica not simplifying expressions with units

Tags: units

Hi I'm having an issue with the Quantity system.

On the guide for units on the wolfram page, there is an example

```
1/2 a t^2 + v t +
x0 /. {a -> Quantity[Subscript[a, d], "Meters"/"Seconds"^2],
t -> Quantity[Subscript[t, d], "Seconds"],
v -> Quantity[Subscript[v, d], "Meters"/"Seconds"],
x0 -> Quantity[Subscript[x0, d], "Meters"]}
```

[image]

However, on my system I get

[image]

This is quite annoying as it does the same for many other physics calculations. I'm almost certain that it used to work but I do not recall changing any settings? Anyone have any idea of how to get this functionality to start working again. Thanks

Comment: I'm running version 12.0, I also have 11.2 installed and the unit simplification works fine

Comment: What is the InputForm (or FullForm) of the resulting expression?

Comment: very strange, I'd tried restarting Mathematica already, but when I just reopened today I was no longer having the issue. I'll add more info if I get this problem again